# Merge app configs from assemblies in exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to merge all the `Properties.Settings` accross different assemblies automatically in the postbuild of my executable into the `app.config` of my executable.

So I have all the configuration sections in my app config for the different assemblies.

Actually for each assembly a configsection needs to be appended automatically to my exe.config including all the properties available.

Comment: Do you want to do this using code, or using a third-party tool? Here's a [third-party tool](http://configmerger.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I am using a client application... Can this thing also spit out app.config? @Jason

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. I just did a quick search for it. So it does look like third-party tools are acceptable?

Comment: As long as they do the job correctly... Yes...

Comment: why not merge manually? you only need very basic xml knowledge

Comment: Because then I have to update manually on two places. Probably members in my team will forget it and then we have a problem... So automatically will be preferrable. I know xml is very easy...

Comment: Can you try the first tool? And also, [maybe this will help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7406/XmlConfigMerge-Merge-config-file-settings). See the very first line of code on that article; it seems to be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your assemblies are added through visual studio project, you can use section grouping int the startup application project to include all the settings from all dependencies.

```
<configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Model.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="Shop.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
```

And add those settings like this:

```
<applicationSettings>
        <Model.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="SiteUrl" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://www.mysite.com</value>
            </setting>
        </Model.Properties.Settings>
        <Shop.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="SynchronisationLoggingEnabled" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
        </Shop.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I know, but I want this process to be automated, so all my section groups are updated accordingly the settings in each project. I'm currently doing this by hand....